# как правильно выводить строки с числом

Tags: java

```
int s = 0;          String seconds = String.format("%02d", s);
int m = 0;          String minutes = String.format("%02d", m);
int h = 0;          String hours = String.format("%02d", h); 
session.sendMessage(new TextMessage(hours+":"+minutes+":"+seconds));
while (s<=60) {
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    s++; 
    session.sendMessage(new TextMessage(hours+":"+minutes+":"+seconds));
}
if (s<60);
m++;
s = 00;
Thread.sleep(1000);
session.sendMessage(new TextMessage(hours+":"+minutes+":"+seconds));
```

Хотел сделать, что бы выводило 00:00:00, выводит как надо, но теперь не меняется значение секунд, что не так?
Без перевода в строку все работает.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У вас внутри цикла `while` значение переменной `s` меняется, но текст `seconds`, который вы отправляете, сформирован до цикла, и значение переменной `s` на него никак не влияет.

В принципе, не понятно зачем три раза делать `String.format`, потом склеивать строки, если можно сразу через `format` сформировать готовую строку, и ее вывести:

```
int s = 0;
int m = 0;
int h = 0;
while (s<60) {
    session.sendMessage(new TextMessage(String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d", h, m, s)));
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    s++; 
}
```

---

Я бы использовал `for` вместо `while` и вывод и задержку только в самом внутреннем цикле:

```
for (int h = 0; h < 60; h++) {
    for (int m = 0; m < 60; m++) {
        for (int s = 0; s < 60; s++) {
            session.sendMessage(new TextMessage(
                String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d", h, m, s)));
                
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: ясно, спасибо! как мне теперь остановить таймер? если я пишу `} if (clientMessage.startsWith("stop")); { break; }`, то он не заканчивает таймер, а продолжает присылать новые значения.

Comment: Это уже другой вопрос. Как вариант запускать эти циклы в отдельном потоке, а при получении сообщения от пользователя этот поток прибивать.